# What’s the origin of reading tens from Right to left?

Tags: numbers

What’s the origin of speaking all teens & tens (E.g. 14, 24) from right to left
(In German)? E.g. in English we do it only with „teens” (e.g 17 - seventeen, not teenseven as would be sensibly easier)? Btw If someone knows the answer for English teens - Please do share too;)

Comment: It used to be the same in English as it is in German. German is simply more conservative.

Comment: Sadly I don't remember the good yt video I've seen on this topic (about language evolution containing this number details). BTW: its not ten-four like twenty-four, its fourteen like vierzehn, both languages are still close in the teens :-)